# get all posts from desired category in json format?

Tags: php, json

```
<?php

  include("../wp-config.php");
  // set header for json mime type
  header('Content-type: application/json;');
  $cat_id=array(12,13,14);
  $post=array('category__in' => $cat_id,'posts_per_page=-1');

  $category_query = new WP_Query($post);

// print_r($category_query);
   while ($category_query->have_posts())
  {

     $jsonpost=$category_query->the_post();
     $id=$post->ID;
     $post_title=get_the_title();
     $image=wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($id, 'thumbnail'));
     $content=strip_tags(apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content));
    /* echo $content;
     echo $image;*/  
     $jsonpost=array('post_title'=>$post_title,'post_content' =>$content,'post_image' => $image);

    /*======== PRODUCT COLLECTION OUTPUT AS JSON FORMAT ======*/

    $output['post_details'] =  $jsonpost;
    echo (json_encode($output,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
  }
 //print_r($jsonpost);exit();   

  $post1=array('cat'=> 12,'order' => 'DESC');
    $category_query1 = new WP_Query($post1);
     while ($category_query1->have_posts())
     {

     $jsonpost1=$category_query1->the_post();
         $id=$post->ID;
     $post_title=get_the_title();
     $image=wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($id, 'thumbnail'));
     $content=strip_tags(apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content));
    $jsonpost1=array('post_title'=>$post_title,'post_content'=>$content,'post_image'=>$image);
     $output1['Latest_news'] =  $jsonpost1;
   /*======== PRODUCT COLLECTION OUTPUT AS JSON FORMAT ======*/

    // print_r($output);
  echo (json_encode($output1,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
    }
  //wp_reset_postdata();

 ?>
```

I'm getting the result as below:

```
{"post_details":
{"post_title":"Breaking-News2","post_content":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\n","post_image":"http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/1022201314344PM_635_nokia-Lumia-1520.jpeg"}
 }
{"post_details":
{"post_title":"breaking news1","post_content":"Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,\n","post_image":"http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/breaking_news.jpg"}
 }
{"post_details":
{"post_title":"standard stories","post_content":"Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,\n","post_image":"http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/index.jpg"}
 }
{"post_details":
{"post_title":"breaking-news","post_content":"The first line of Lorem Ipsum, &#8220;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..&#8221;, comes from a line in section 1.10.32.\n","post_image":"http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/breakingNews.jpg"}
 }
 {"post_details":
{"post_title":"call-out","post_content":"Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#8217;s standard dummy tex\n","post_image":"http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/callout.jpg"}
 }
 {"Latest_news":
{"post_title":"Breaking-News2","post_content":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\n","post_image":"http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/1022201314344PM_635_nokia-Lumia-1520.jpeg"}
 }
 {"Latest_news":
{"post_title":"breaking news1","post_content":"Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,\n","post_image":"http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/breaking_news.jpg"}
 }
 {"Latest_news":
{"post_title":"breaking-news","post_content":"The first line of Lorem Ipsum, &#8220;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..&#8221;, comes from a line in section 1.10.32.\n","post_image":"http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/breakingNews.jpg"}
 }
```

But I want to display my response in the following way:

```
{
   "post_details":
   [
       {
           "post_title": "Breaking-News2",
           "post_content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. ",
           "post_image": "http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/1022201314344PM_635_nokia-Lumia-1520.jpeg"
       },
       {
           "post_title": "breaking news1",
           "post_content": "Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, ",
           "post_image": "http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/breaking_news.jpg"
       },
       {
           "post_title": "standard stories",
           "post_content": "Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, ",
           "post_image": "http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/index.jpg"
       },
       {
           "post_title": "breaking-news",
           "post_content": "The first line of Lorem Ipsum, “Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..”, comes from a line in section 1.10.32. ",
           "post_image": "http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/breakingNews.jpg"
       },
       {
           "post_title": "call-out",
           "post_content": "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy tex ",
           "post_image": "http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/callout.jpg"
       }
   ],
   "Latest_posts":
   [
       {
           "post_title": "Breaking-News2",
           "post_content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. ",
           "post_image": "http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/1022201314344PM_635_nokia-Lumia-1520.jpeg"
       },
       {
           "post_title": "breaking news1",
           "post_content": "Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, ",
           "post_image": "http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/breaking_news.jpg"
       },
       {
           "post_title": "breaking-news",
           "post_content": "The first line of Lorem Ipsum, “Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..”, comes from a line in section 1.10.32. ",
           "post_image": "http://localhost/police/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/breakingNews.jpg"
       }
   ]
}
```

In the above result, all posts in all categories are displayed in individual requests data, but i want to get the output in same data request.i'm using the **json format** first time.So i'm in need!!Help me!!

Comment: Collect the `$output` and echo it *after* the `foreach`.

Comment: I did test it @DOC ASAREL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points to note:

#### 1. You dont want to echo json strings in the loop.

What you need to do is to make a proper associative array in the for loop. And once it is made via the loop and loop completes, you can `json_encode` the complete associative array and echo it.

#### 2. improper use of `$jsonposts` variable

In the code you have quoted, the `$jsonposts` variable is used internally in the loop to make individual post arrays which are displayed immediately. It can be declared when you need it. That is inside the loop. Also you can have a global array (I have put `op` in the code) to which you could push each element of the complete output in the loop iterations and finally encode it ad send.

#### 3. proper code indentation

please indent the code properly so that I would be helpful to understand the flow when you read it at a later stage or provide to others for support.

```
include("../wp-config.php");
header('Content-type: application/json;');

/* Use this variable for preparing the result to be send back as json response */
$op = array();

$cat_args=array(
   'orderby' => 'name',
   'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories=get_categories($cat_args);

foreach($categories as $category) 
{
    $args=array(
     'showposts' => -1,
      'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
      'caller_get_posts'=>1
     );
    $posts=get_posts($args);
    if ($posts) {
        foreach($posts as $post) {

            /* prepare individual item to be pushed into the result array */
            $jsonpost = array();
            $jsonpost['post_title']=get_the_title();
            $jsonpost['content']=apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
            $jsonpost['image_url']=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($id, 'thumbnail') );  
            $jsonpost['date']=get_the_date('d F Y');

            /* push the item on to the result array */
            $op[] = array('request'  => 'all_posts',
                          'data'=> $jsonpost)

        }
    } 

}
/* array should be complete at this point encode it as json string and send back */
echo json_encode($op);
```

#### update to comments below

The expected json result you are showing in question is not valid json. You may check the same via jsonlint.com. A suggestion would be to make it like

```
  {"request":"all_posts","data": [

    {"post_title":"Breaking News story1","content":"...."},
    {"post_title":"Breaking News story1","content":"...."},
    /* repeat elements here */

  ] }
```

#### updated to comments below

To change your code sothat it produces a JSON like the one mentioned above here. You have to make the following changes in the code mentioned above.

change the line

```
$op[] = array('request'  => 'all_posts',
                      'data'=> $jsonpost);
```

to

```
$op[] = $jsonpost;
```

and change the last line from

```
echo json_encode($op);
```

to

```
echo json_encode(array('request'  => 'all_posts',
                      'data'=> $op));
```

Comment: Thank you so much your useful explanation @mithunsatheesh. Actually I'm getting the responses are in individual data, but here i want that all the results are displayed in a single request data...Am i asking correctly?

Comment: You mean to say, you want the response as a single json array right? You can achieve it by following the code above. Or update the question with latest code if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: i have updated my question.Just see the updated format.

Comment: the sample you have put is not valid json. you can check it at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Hai @mithunsatheesh : how do i bulid it with proper associative array?please guide me

Comment: ya i have changed it according to your update but still i didnot get my desired output,Shall i post my update code  @mithunsatheesh

Comment: @ mithunsatheesh i have update my code,Kindly check!

Comment: @ mithunsatheesh When i put my json_encode($output) after while loop, i'm getting single post from my first added category.I want to get all the post in my selected category id.

Comment: @keerthi: right now u got 2 while loops in that. are they needed.??

Comment: @ mithunsatheesh: yes ji.I want to display all post in category id i took and also display latest posts from my desired category.

Comment: do you want to put the results from both loops into same array? as you mention in question `all_posts`? or differentiate because they are different results right?

Comment: @ mithunsatheesh : ya...both are different result, but the results inside the **post_details** are in same array, results inside the **Latest_news** will be in same array

Comment: @keerthi : see [**this gist**](https://gist.github.com/mithunsatheesh/3a7cd3ae546ebe4e77dc).. is this what you want? if not update your question where you the requred output format. Its wrong. Also read the comments in code to understand the flow so that u can tweak urself

Comment: Ya this want i want @Mr.mithunsatheesh

Comment: hope you resolved your issue. If not update your question with the latest code and the output format u require.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
         include("../wp-config.php");
         header('Content-type: application/json;');
         $jsonpost = array();

         //for each category, show all posts
         $cat_args=array(
           'orderby' => 'name',
           'order' => 'ASC'
         );
    $categories=get_categories($cat_args);
   //print_r($categories);
   foreach($categories as $category) 
   {
     $args=array(
         'showposts' => -1,
          'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
          'caller_get_posts'=>1
         );
      //print_r($args);
      $posts=get_posts($args);
       if ($posts) {
         foreach($posts as $post) {
          //setup_postdata($post);
            $jsonpost['post_title']=get_the_title();
            $jsonpost['content']=apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
            $jsonpost['image_url']=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($id, 'thumbnail') );  
            $jsonpost['date']=get_the_date('d F Y');

            //echo $jsonpost['post_title'];
         $output =  array('request'  => 'all_posts',
                          'data'=> $jsonpost);
          /*======== PRODUCT COLLECTION OUTPUT AS JSON FORMAT ====== */


    } // foreach($posts
  echo (json_encode($output));
  } // if ($posts

}   // foreach($categories
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try the below code.

```
<?php
     include("../wp-config.php");
     header('Content-type: application/json;');
     // create new array to add all posts to
     $jsonposts = array();

     //for each category, show all posts
     $cat_args=array(
       'orderby' => 'name',
       'order' => 'ASC'
     );
    $categories=get_categories($cat_args);
    //print_r($categories);
    foreach($categories as $category) 
    {
      $args=array(
         'showposts' => -1,
          'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
          'caller_get_posts'=>1
         );
      //print_r($args);
      $posts=get_posts($args);
       if ($posts) {
         foreach($posts as $post) {
          //setup_postdata($post);
            $jsonpost = array();
            $jsonpost['post_title']=get_the_title();
            $jsonpost['content']=apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
            $jsonpost['image_url']=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($id, 'thumbnail') );  
            $jsonpost['date']=get_the_date('d F Y');

            //echo $jsonpost['post_title'];
            // add the post to the new array
            $jsonposts[] = $jsonpost;

          /*======== PRODUCT COLLECTION OUTPUT AS JSON FORMAT ====== */


    } // foreach($posts
     // format as JSON
     $output =  array('request'  => 'all_posts',
                          'data'=> $jsonposts);
     echo (json_encode($output));

  } // if ($posts

}   // foreach($categories
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the WordPress REST API: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

GET a URL like this:

http://your-site.com/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=dogs

Keep in mind that the root URL for the API can change with a filter, do not assume its default value. Use `json_url()` instead.

Using the WordPress HTTP API:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( $url, json_url() );

//make sure response isn't an error
if ( ! is_wp_error( $response )  ) {

    //get the posts as an array
   $posts = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
}
```

Using jQuery/AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: true,
        url: rootURL + '/posts?filter[category_name]=dogs,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(posts) {
            //do stuff with posts
        }
    });
```

For the jQuery/AJAX example, be sure to localize the value of `json_url()` into the DOM using `wp_localize_script()`.

Answer (score 0):

**First you need to register function for GET method. syntax is given below.**

```
  // GET All Posts using API
  add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wp_api_show_Posts_endpoints' );
  function wp_api_show_Posts_endpoints() {
    register_rest_route( 'showPost', '/v2', array(
          'methods' => 'GET',
          'callback' => 'showPosts_callback',
      ));
  }
```

Here I taken **showPosts_callback** function for logic, (which contents need to fetch on json view)

This is **callback function** for **GET Method** logic.

```
  function showPosts_callback( $request_data ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $data = array();

    $table        = 'wp_posts';
    $parameters = $request_data->get_params();
    $post_type = $parameters['post_type'];

    if($post_type!=''){
        $re_query     = "SELECT * FROM $table where post_type='$post_type'";
        $pre_results  = $wpdb->get_results($re_query,ARRAY_A); 
        foreach ($pre_results as $key => $value) {
            $post_id = $value['ID'];

            // Adding selected categories
            $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
            $cats = array();

            foreach($post_categories as $c){
                $cat = get_category( $c );
                $cats[] = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );
            }
            $pre_results[$key]['all_selected_categories']=$cats;

            // Adding post featured image.
            $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full'); 
            $pre_results[$key]['featured_img_url']=$featured_img_url;

            // Adding post metaboxes
            $meta = array();
            $meta = get_metadata($post_type,$post_id);
            $pre_results[$key]['metafields'] = $meta;

          }
        return $pre_results;

    }else{
        $data['status']=' false ';
        return $data;

    } 
  }
```

Then you can fetch record from anywhere using this url

```
Syntax:
 www.yourdomain.com/wp-json/showPost/v2?post_type=post
```